# RegEx pattern to capture comma-separated list of words

Tags: regex

Does anyone know a repeatable RegEx pattern to capture the words between a comma separated list?

For example:

```
City,State,Latitude,Longitude

// $1,$2,$3,$4
```

This is for Find and Replace in an IDE, so the `.split` method provided by most programming languages is not a solution. Also no look-aheads / look-arounds please, these are not universally supported.

**Clarifications:** (1) just need to capture comma-separated words on a single line - not across multiple lines, (2) a solution to the example would be enough.

Comment: You have not accepted any solution yet, aren't they working  as expected? If not, what is the real problem? Note that it is not clear what the issue you are having, just some task with unclear requirements. Please edit the question and add details: how many fields are expected, if their amount is fixed or not, can the fields span across lines, can there be any other caveats we are not aware of. The term "best" can only be applied to solutions that we know the requirements of. Just "give me the best regex" is no requirement.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - the requirement is to provide a repeatable regex pattern that can capture N number of comma separated tokens, which is better than the solution that I've provided (which is currently the top answer). Also, you're reading too much into the word "best"... simply said "This is my best solution at the moment".

Comment: @WJS - "Why a regex?" - As explained in the question "This is for Find and Replace in an IDE" (which accepts RegEx patterns)

Comment: If you wanf to stay on one line and work in VSCode or VS you may use your pattern and your question is off-topic because there is no code that is not working here. If you use NPP or SublimeText, the pattern you have may span across multiple lines in very specific cases you just need to add `\n` into each character class. If there may be fewer than four fields, you should use optional noncapturing groups.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - "If there may be fewer than four fields, you should use optional noncapturing groups" - the words may need to be captured to be replaced with a sentence - like `This $1 is in $2 with coordinates of $3 and $4`. Capturing is needed regardless of word count.

Comment: So, what is the problem with your solution? Why did you post the question?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - "If you use NPP or SublimeText, the pattern you have may span across multiple lines in very specific cases you just need to add \n into each character class." - feel free to provide your own answer to the question

Comment: And what is the tool you are using?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - "Why did you post the question?" - because I couldn't find a similar question on StackOverflow, and I thought this might be useful to other developers who had a similar problem. "So, what is the problem with your solution?" - There's not a problem per se, but maybe someone has a better solution or ideas that can help strengthen the solution.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - "And what is the tool you are using?" POSIX extended RegEx.

Comment: That is not a tool, that is the regex flavor, and it is very strange because IDEs I know of all use NFA regex engines, and POSIX ERE is only used in *NIX.

Answer (score 1):

If our inputs are as simple as that, your best solution is just fine, and `^` may not be necessary, and these expressions might work:

```
([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*)
([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+)
```

or if start and end anchors are necessary:

```
^([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*)$
^([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+)$
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: `([^,]+),?` didn't work for me. Captures `$1` only.

Answer (score 1):

Try this with `$1`, tested with VsCode

```regex
\s?(\w+)\s?,?
```

Comment: Answers the example provided if repeated as `(\w+),(\w+),(\w+),(\w+)`. However, does not handle spaces that might exist between words.

Comment: @tfmontague sure thing, just added optional spaces in there.

Answer (score 0):

This is my best solution at the moment

```
^([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*)$
```

Comment: Perhaps just as a side note, the negated character class `[^,]` will also match a newline and `*` will match 0+ times.